# Please i am new in prolog can some body help me in this exercice

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

Write a predicate `less/2`, such that if t1 represents n1 and t2 represents n2, then
`less(t1, t2)` succeeds iff n1 < n2. For example, `less(s(z), s(s(s(z))))` should
succeed, and `less(s(z), s(z))` should fail. If t1 is an uninstantiated logic variable,
while t2 is a proper representation of a natural number n2, then the predicate
should enumerate all numbers less than n2. For example, the query

```
?- less(X, s(s(z))).
```

should succeed with `X = z` and `X = s(z)` (not necessarily in that order).

Comment: The common notation for [tag:successor-arithmetics] is `0`, `s(0)`, `s(s(0))` etc. And not `z` for `0`. Look at other questions under the tag [tag:successor-arithmetics]!

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

```
ls(0,s(_)).
ls(s(X),s(Y)) :- ls(X,Y).
```

Here are some example runs:

```
?- ls(s(0),s(s(s(0)))).
Yes
?- ls(s(s(0)),s(0)).
No
```

Bye